# How to install MySQLdb in python2.7 installing in virtualenv

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, mysql-python

How I can solve [this one](http://dumpz.org/195742/)?

Also I have MySQL-python-1.2.3 dist in *venv/lib*.
And before that it was installed like python setup.py install
It's working correctly if only I'm using:

```
$ python
>>> import MySQLdb
```

without virtualenv

May be exists some way to install this one to any chosen virtualenv?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to python/Lib/site-package and copy all mysqldb.... to your virtual enviroment

Comment: I think I'm tried it already, but unsuccessful. Don't have idea - why.

Comment: No, when I type ~$ uname -i >>> i386